# How can I use a local variable declared in one function and implement it to another function? (Without global variables or calling the function)

Tags: python

```
import socket, sys

def create_socket(): # Creates a socket which connects two or more computers together
    host = ""
    port = 9999
    socket_ = socket.socket()
    try:
        host
        port
        socket_
        
    except socket.error as msg:
        print("Socket Creation Error: " + str(msg))

    return host, port, socket_


def bind_Socket(): # Binds the Socket and listening for connections

    host, port, socket_ = create_socket()
    try:
        host
        port
        socket_
        print("Binding the Socket: " + str(port))
        
        socket_.bind((host, port))
        socket_.listen(5)
        
    except socket.error as msg:
        print("Socket Creation Error: " + str(msg) + "Retrying....")
        bind_Socket()
    return host, port, socket_



def socket_accept(): # Establishes a connection with a client (socket must be listening)
    host, port, socket_ = bind_Socket()
    conn, address = socket_.accept()
    send_command(conn)
    print("Connection successful... " + "IP: " + address[0] + "\n" + "Port: " + address[1])

def send_command(conn): # Sends command to client
    host, port, socket_ = bind_Socket()
    cmd = ""
    while (cmd != "Quit"):
        cmd = input("Enter a command: ")
        if(len(str.encode(cmd)) > 0):
            conn.send(str.encode(cmd))
            client_response = str(conn.recv(1024,"UTF-8"))
            print(client_response, end="")
    else:
        conn.close()
        socket_.close()
        sys.exit()
    
        
def main():
    create_socket()
    bind_Socket()
    socket_accept()
main()
```

The problem is when I call the `bind_Socket()` in `main()` It will print out **"Binding the Socket: 9999"** twice because it's also being called in the function `socket_accept()`. I just want to know how to use the same variables declared in one function and implement it in another without using global variables or calling the function like I did.

Comment: *Don't* call `bind_socket` twice…!? `socket_accept` calls `bind_socket` calls `create_socket`, so you only need to call `socket_accept` in `main` and none of the others…

Answer (score 0):

Functions can return objects to be used by other functions as arguments.

Set main up like this:

```
def main():
    _, _, socket_ = bind_Socket()
    socket_accept(socket_)
```

Then update `_accept` to accept args:

```
def socket_accept(socket_): 
    conn, address = socket_.accept()
    ....
```

Thus passing the socket object to the accept method.